# Override order creation in PrestaShop back-office

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have PrestaShop 1.7.2.0.

I need to customize the page in back-office where new orders are created. I want to improve products combinations selection, so just a part of the page.

In URL I see `...controller=AdminOrders&addorder...`, so I guess the controller is

```
/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php
```

With a file search I found that the template that renders the page must be

```
/admin753xeprta/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/form.tpl
```

My questions are:

1. **How should I customize these files?** Is it better to just override them on my installation or to create a module that does it (if it is allowed)?
2. **Where should I put custom files?** I tried many places, with no success. I'm getting crazy with folder structure, especially because it seems to change with every PS version and PS documentation is spread on various version-specific sections...
3. With AdminOrdersController.php I think I can derive the class and overload just those methods that I need. But I'm wondering **whether in the case of form.tpl I should override the entire file** (duplicate it and change the parts that I need).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **module** and use overrides within it (if you really need it for the task).

Inside a module you can change some parts of the Prestashop PHP flow with **hooks**:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x

But there is no hook to change all data of `controllers/orders/form.tpl`. If the task is only about the **template**, you can override it placing a file
`/override/controllers/admin/templates/orders/form.tpl`.

In a case of template changes, you do  not need to copy all the file, just override it:
http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/smarty/parent-child-feature.html#extending-the-same-template
http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/smarty/template-inheritance.html

If you need new data in the template, you can **override the controller**:
`/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`.

Comment: Thanks @Indrė, I tried to put custom files in your suggested locations, but it seems that PrestaShop doesn't get affected by these overrides. I also cleaned /app/cache. Is there something more to do?

Comment: What exactly have you placed and where?

Comment: I copied `/admin/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/form.tpl` into `/modules/mymodule/override/controllers/admin/templates/orders/form.tpl` and changed those part of my interest.

I created file `/modules/mymodule/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`, subclassing the original class and overriding those methods of my interest.
Now I'm wondering if you meant override root folder (`/override`) or the override folder but inside a module (`/modules/mymodule/override`). I give for granted they are both correct places for overriding, am I wrong? Thank you @Indrė!